# Javascript add a result based on choice (HTML, CSS JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page, there is a datalist and an input type radio, I would like by pressing the button on the bottom to calculate based to the choice on the data list (each choice should be attached to a value ex. Κρητη with 85 etc) and the choice on the radio (first dot should multipl the value from the datalist by one, the second by two etc.). I made some changes translating in english for it to be easier. To explain more, what I mean is: the user selects an option from the data list, in my example the options are some islands, the user also selects how many nights he wishes to stay on the island. Each islands has its own price. What i wish to do is calculate the cost (islands price per night * number of nights staying), my question is how do i save the users selections and how do i save the variables so i can do the calculations. I hope I've been a little more understood.

```html
<div id="nhsia">

  <label for="destinationselect">select destination:</label>
  <input list="choices" id="destinations" onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="setImage(value);" name="destinations" />

  <datalist id="choices">
    <option value="island1">
    <option value="island2">
    <option value="island3">
    <option value="island4">
    <option value="island5">
  </datalist>


</div>

<div id="prices">
  <p id="priceisland1">for island 1 is 85 a night</p>
  <p id="priceisland2">for island 2 is 70 a night</p>
  <p id="priceisland3">for island 3 is 65 a night</p>
  <p id="priceisland4">for island 4 is 55 a night</p>
  <p id="priceisland5">for island 5 is 60 a night</p>
</div>

<div id="nights">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="1">
    ONE NIGHT
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="2">
    TWO NIGHTS
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="3">
    THREE NIGHTS
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="4">
    FOUR NIGHTS
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="5">
    FIVE NIGHTS
  </label>
</div>


<div id="results">
  <p id="calculate"> CALCULATE VACATION COST!</p>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="calculate!" />
  <p id="results">results: <span></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: could you explain your question more precisely, because now i'm not able to understand what the desired result should look like. I even don't understand what values mean, I understand only few words, because I'm not greek. Maybe you mean how to acces date from your inputs when some button is clicked?

Comment: I don't see any values in your html...also, since you are asking in english, would be nice if your example code was in english too. Help us understand you if you want any help...

Comment: I made some changes translating in english for it to be easier. To explain more, what I mean is: the user selects an option from the data list, in my example the options are some islands, the user also selects how many nights he wishes to stay on the island. Each islands has its own price. What i wish to do is calculate the cost (islands price per night * number of nights staying), my question is how do i save the users selections and how do i save the variables so i can do the calculations. I hope I've been a little more understood. Thank u though for your intrest <3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should edit the question to move your comment to the question itself. Your comment is more clear with what you are expecting. You'll have better luck getting an answer. Also, you should add your JavaScript to the question since it's necessary to the debug the actual issue.

Comment: I havent written anything in js wet I dont know where to start and how to actually save the variables so I can calculate them.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this problem is as follows:

```js
// caching a reference to the <form> element in the page,
// document.querySelector() returns either the first node
// that matches the supplied CSS selector or null:
const form = document.querySelector('form'),
// here we have an Object Literal, which matches the
// islands to their per-night price (as the variable
// name implies):
    costPerNight = {
      'island1': 85,
      'island2': 70,
      'island3': 65,
      'island4': 55,
      'island5': 60,
    };

// we bind the anonymous Arrow function as the event-handler for
// the 'input' event when it's fired on any descendant element
// within the <form>, and pass the Event Object into that
// function:
form.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  // here we get a reference to the <form> on which the event-
  // handler was bound:
  let form = e.currentTarget,
  // here we get a reference to the element upon which the
  // 'input' event was originall fired:
      affected = e.target,
  // here we use Element.querySelectorAll() to retrive all
  // elements within the <form> that match the supplied
  // CSS selector; Element.querySelectorAll() returns a
  // non-live NodeList of elements, and this is converted
  // to an Array using the Array-literal operator along with
  // the spread syntax:
      checked = [...form.querySelectorAll(':checked')]
      // we then use the anonymous Arrow function of the the
      // Array.prototype.filter() to filter that Array of nodes,
      // passing the current node of the Array of Nodes into
      // the function:
        .filter(
          (el) => {
            // using Element.matches() to obtain a Boolean (true/false)
            // to see if the element matches the CSS selector, so we're
            // checking if the current node is an <option> element, and
            // that the element is the defaultSelected option (this
            // returns a Boolean, true if it is, false if not), and checking
            // if it is also disabled (again, returning a Boolean).
            // The reason for this is that by default the first <option>
            // of a <select> element will be selected by default, and will
            // match the ':checked' CSS selector, but I want to ensure that
            // the user is forced to choose their own preference rather
            // than accepting the default:
            if (el.matches('option') && el.defaultSelected && el.disabled) {
              // if all of the above evaluates to true, then we return
              // false and remove the <option> from the Array of nodes:
              return false;
            }
            // otherwise we return true:
            return true
          }),
      // retrieving the <fieldset> elements:
      fieldsets = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset'),
      // a switch, that assesses whether the number of
      // :checked items is equal to the number of
      // <fieldset> elements:
      haveBoth = checked.length === fieldsets.length,
      // caching references to elements:
      result = document.querySelector('#result'),
      cost = document.querySelector('#cost');

  // here we assess the result of haveBoth, and invert it;
  // so if we have the same number of :checked elements as
  // the number of <fieldset> elements haveBoth would be
  // true, and here we invert that to false (and vice versa).
  // We want to enter this branch of the if only when hasBoth
  // is false, so we invert the false to true, if hasBoth
  // is itself true we don't wish to enter this branch so
  // we invert the true to false in order to skip it:
  if (!haveBoth) {
    // here we hide the result element when hasBoth is false,
    // and inverted to true:
    result.hidden = true;
  } else {
    // here we use Array.prototype.map() to iterate over the
    // Array of Nodes to return a different Array based on
    // that existing Array:
    checked.map(
      // we again use the anonymous Arrow function of the
      // Array.prototype.map() method to pass the current
      // node of the Array into the function:
      (el) => {
        // we retrieve the closest ancestor-element of the
        // current Node which has a 'name' attribute; in
        // the case of <input> elements that is the <input>
        // element itself, and in the case of the <option>
        // elements it is the parent <select> element:
        let hasName = el.closest('[name]'),
          // we use destructuring assignment to assign the
          // named property-values of the hasName Node to
          // the supplied variables:
          {
            name,
            value
          } = hasName;
          
        // here we use the HTMLOrForeignElement.datalist API
        // to create a data-* attribute on the cost element,
        // setting its property-value to that held in the
        // current value variable:
        cost.dataset[name] = value;
        // we then return an Object literal, with two
        // properties, name and value:
        return {
          'name': hasName.name,
          'value': hasName.value
        }
      // we use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
      // Array of Objects returned by Array.prototype.map(),
      // passing the current Object of that Array into the
      // function as the 'obj' variable:
      }).forEach(
        // here we use a template literal to retrieve supply the
        // name of the current Object to document.querySelector()
        // to retrieve the node that will hold the current Object's
        // value property-value:
        (obj) => document.querySelector(`#${obj.name}`).textContent = obj.value
      );
      
    // here we use another template-literal to compose the key with
    // which we can use bracket-notation to access the per-night cost
    // of the selected island, retrieving that chosen island's number
    // from the created data-* attribute on the cost Node (earlier):
    let perNight = costPerNight[`island${cost.dataset.island}`],
    // here we retrieve the number of nights the user has chosen to stay,
    // again using the HTMLOrForeignElement.dataset API, and then
    // use parseInt() (with a radix of 10) to convert that string into
    // a base-10 number:
        nights = parseInt(cost.dataset.nights, 10);
        
    // we update the text-content of the cost element to be equal to
    // the result of multiplying the perNight and nights variables:
    cost.textContent = perNight * nights;
    // we set the hidden property of the result element to false (so
    // that it becomes visible):
    result.hidden = false;
  }
});
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 0.5em;
}

fieldset {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

fieldset + div {
  flex: 2 0 auto;
}

h2::after {
  content: ':';
}

select,
label {
  width: 80%;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

label span {
  margin-inline-start: 0.5em;
}

input:checked + span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#result {
  grid-row: auto;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

#result span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#island:not(:empty)::before {
  content: 'Island ';
}

#nights:not(:empty)::after {
  content: ' nights';
}

#cost:not(:empty)::before {
  content: attr(data-currency);
}
```

```html
<!-- Because we're taking inputs from a user we're going to use a <form>, and
     associated form-elements, to gather that information: -->
<form action="#" method="post">
  <!-- grouping related information together using <fieldset> elements: -->
  <fieldset>
    <!-- using a <legend> element to provide a clear heading, though
         we also use a nested <h2> element to prompt the user to
         answer (this could be a <label>, but I wanted to have the <h2>
         elements to behave similarly in both <fieldset> elements: -->
    <legend>Destination</legend>
    <h2>Which Island</h2>
    <select name="island">
      <!-- here we explicitly specify that the first <option>,
           which contains an instruction to the user, is both
           selected (so it's defaultSelected property will be
           true, and that it is disabled so that it cannot be
           selected by the user: -->
      <option disabled selected>Please select:</option>
      <option value="1">Island 1 for 85 per night</option>
      <option value="2">Island 2 for 70 per night</option>
      <option value="3">Island 3 for 65 per night</option>
      <option value="4">Island 4 for 55 per night</option>
      <option value="5">Island 5 for 60 per night</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Duration</legend>
    <h2>How long are you staying</h2>
    <label><input type="radio" name="nights" value="1"><span>1 night</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="nights" value="2"><span>2 nights</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="nights" value="3"><span>3 nights</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="nights" value="4"><span>4 nights</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="nights" value="5"><span>5 nights</span></label>
  </fieldset>
  <!-- we use the "hidden" attribute to hide the element on page-load, this element
       will show the user their choices once those choices have been made: -->
  <div id="result" hidden>
    You have selected <span id="island"></span> for <span id="nights"></span>, at a cost of <span id="cost" data-currency="€"></span>.
  </div>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2hydus8z/2/).

References:

- [Array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Bracket-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).
- [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
- [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
- [`HTMLOrForeignElement.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).
- [Logical AND (`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND).
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using javascipt, it's better store all your lists in one place and generate html instead.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "island 1",
    price: 85
  },
  {
    name: "island 2",
    price: 70
  },
  {
    name: "island 3",
    price: 65
  },
  {
    name: "island 4",
    price: 55
  },
  {
    name: "island 5",
    price: 60
  }
]

const destinationsCtl = document.getElementById("destinations"),
      calculateCtl = document.getElementById("calculate"),
      choicesCtl = document.getElementById("choices"),
      pricesCtl = document.getElementById("prices"),
      priceTempl = prices.querySelector(".price"),
      nightsCtl = document.getElementById("nights"),
      nightsList = nightsCtl.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="night"]'),
      resultsCtl = document.getElementById("results"),
      regId = new RegExp("\\${(" + Object.keys(data[0]).join("|") + ")}", "g");

prices.removeChild(priceTempl);

var selectedDest = null,
    selectedNights = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = data[i].name;
  option._dataId = i;
  option.label = data[i].price + " a night";
  choicesCtl.appendChild(option);
  
  price = priceTempl.cloneNode(true);
  price.innerHTML = price.innerHTML.replace(regId, (a, key) => data[i][key]);
  pricesCtl.appendChild(price);
}

for(let i = 0; i < nightsList.length; i++)
{
  nightsList[i].addEventListener("input", (e) => 
  {
    selectedNights = ~~e.target.value;
    setImage();
  });
}

function setImage(dest)
{
  if (dest === undefined)
    dest = destinationsCtl;

  selectedDest = null;
  for(let i = 0; i < dest.list.options.length; i++)
  {
    const selected = dest.list.options[i].value === dest.value;
    if (selected)
    {
      selectedDest = dest.list.options[i]._dataId;
    }
    pricesCtl.children[i].classList.toggle("selected", selected);
  }
  calculate();
}

function calculate()
{
  if (selectedDest === null || !selectedNights)
    return;

  const price = data[selectedDest].price,
        destination = data[selectedDest].name,
        nights = selectedNights,
        totalPrice =  price * nights;
         
  resultsCtl.textContent = `${totalPrice} for ${nights} nights at ${destination}`;
}

setImage();
```

```css
.price.selected
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="nhsia">

  <label for="destinationselect">select destination:</label>
  <input list="choices" id="destinations" oninput="setImage(this);" name="destinations" />

  <datalist id="choices">
  </datalist>


</div>

<div id="prices">
  <p class="price">for ${name} is ${price} a night</p>
</div>

<div id="nights">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="1">
    ONE NIGHT
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="2">
    TWO NIGHTS
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="3">
    THREE NIGHTS
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="4">
    FOUR NIGHTS
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="night" value="5">
    FIVE NIGHTS
  </label>
</div>


<div class="results">
  <p>results: <span id="results"></span></p>
</div>
```